# Managed Package : Deploy Modified Picklist from one sandbox to another

Tags: managed-package, deployment, picklist, financial-services-cloud

I have modified a picklist (added new values) that is part of a managed package (Financial services cloud). Now I want to deploy this modified picklist to another sandbox which also has the managed package installed.
When I deploy the same using sfdx force:mdapi:deploy, I get the following error

"Cannot add component of type:CustomField named: Account.FinServ__BranchCode__c subjectId: to another package because it is an installed component."

I do not want to manually add the entries in the other org. How can I deploy this?
My package.xml for deployment has only one entry

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
         <members>Account.FinServ__BranchCode__c</members> 
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <version>52.0</version>    
</Package>
```

Answer (score -4):

I manage the ZuppIO project.

In your case, I can recommend one more deployment method.

To avoid having to manually add records to another organization/organizations, try using ZuppIO. With ZuppIO you can deploy picklist values of any managed custom field to each subscriber organization that has the same package installed, as well as many other types of metadata. Regardless of the number of subscriber organizations, you can deploy all changes in one operation.

By the way, ZuppIO is free on AppExchange with no limits or any hidden costs.

Check it out, I thought it might be a good fit for you guys.

Comment: Given the previous spam campaign here involving this product, I will tell people to avoid it. You might want to spend some time making honest contributions to this community before trying to peddle your wares.